# Compilation error while migrating Jersey from 1.x to 2.x

Tags: java, maven, jersey, pom.xml, jersey-2.0

My pom file contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
  <version>2.21.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The error as appears in the log:
**Updated error:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze) @ 
 api-services ---
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.1:compile
[WARNING]    org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-
   jackson:jar:2.22.1:compile
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze) on project api-services: Dependency problems found -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:analyze-only (analyze) on project api-services: Dependency problems found
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Dependency problems found
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.analyze.AbstractAnalyzeMojo.execute(AbstractAnalyzeMojo.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
```

**Update:**
After removing the above dependencies, I managed to build my project.
So it looks like one of the above requires other dependencies. Any ideas?

**Update 1:**
This is how analyse is defined

```
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>analyse</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
```

Comment: "I am getting error", what error ?

Comment: Which compilation errors are you getting? Can you post part of them since they are actually part of the problem?

Comment: I updated my post with the error.
Thats the only thing I see.

Comment: you cut off the error message to soon. what comes after "Failed to"?

Comment: @wemu I updated the post

Comment: The analyze-only goal is pointing out that there are dependency issues... are there some other errors/messages displayed?

Comment: No, rather than that, I have some warnings about unused dependencies.

Comment: I don't think this is a compile error. as Kevon Hooke pointed out the messages are from the dependency plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html - can you have a look how that is configured? By default it should not let a build fail (mvn help:effective-pom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So indeed we had a goal to analyze the pom (we have it on the parent pom). This analyze just make sure we don't declare duplicate things in the sons pom.
Once I removed the duplicates, everything is was build.
BTW: By removing this goal I will have build success as well.